# mysql query with a max() of another table for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, date, max

Here is my query:

```
SELECT loc.id, loc.nom, loc.prenom, loc.num_tel, loc.num_fixe, bat.adresse, b.date_entree, b.date_sortie, p.date FROM locataires AS loc, bail AS b, apparts AS ap, batiments as bat, clients as cli, paye as p WHERE loc.id = b.idloc AND b.idappart = ap.id AND ap.idbat = bat.id AND bat.idcli = cli. id AND loc.id = b.idloc AND ap.id = b.idappart AND p.idloc = loc.id AND cli.email ="ben@test.be"
```

This query gives :

[image]

But i want the last date ( max(p.date) ) for each person

(NB: there'is people living in the same building, that's why some have the same adress)

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `Max(p.date)` with `Group By` on all other columns.

```
    SELECT loc.id, loc.nom, loc.prenom, loc.num_tel, loc.num_fixe, bat.adresse,
     b.date_entree, b.date_sortie, MAX(p.date) as Date 
    FROM locataires AS loc, bail AS b, apparts AS ap, 
    batiments as bat, clients as cli, paye as p 
    WHERE loc.id = b.idloc AND b.idappart = ap.id AND ap.idbat = bat.id 
AND bat.idcli = cli. id AND loc.id = b.idloc 
AND ap.id = b.idappart AND p.idloc = loc.id 
AND cli.email ="ben@test.be"
    Group By loc.id, loc.nom, loc.prenom, loc.num_tel, loc.num_fixe, bat.adresse,
     b.date_entree, b.date_sortie
```

Comment: Thank you ! It was more easy than i thought. You can even just group by loc.id and its working.